# Is there a generator to create a table in MongoDB just like in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mongodb, computed-column, data-collection

I'm a newbie in mongoDB, and I just would like to ask a simple question. In creating tables in MongoDB, do you go ahead in MongoDB compass and create the fields in a collection, or is there a command where you can generate the table fields declared in the model just like Laravel's `php artisan migrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up schema validation to enforce what field names are permitted/required, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#schema-validation